# switch statement with multiple values in variable

Tags: javascript

I am going through the Odin project and trying to learn each concept well before moving on. My expectation for this switch statement would be for the data values inside the variable 'fruit' to trigger the alerts of 'orange', and if I change orange it should trigger the alert for 'pear'.

When I do this the only case that works is for pear, orange is passed over completely. I tried to google how to make this into an array to work but couldn't find any more basic examples. How do I make this work?

```
fruit = ("orange", "apple", "pear");


switch (fruit) {
    case "orange":
        alert('orange is a fruit')
        break;
    case "hotdog":
        alert('hot dog is meat')
        break;
    case "pear":
        alert('pear is a fruit')
    default:
        document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = 'NONE';
}
```

Comment: fruit = ("orange", "apple", "pear"); is not javascript code. did you mean fruit = ["orange", "apple", "pear"]; ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Comma Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) is causing your assignment to `fruit` to be the last operand - in this case `'pear'`. If you changed the order, whatever was last would be the value that is stored in `fruit`.

You could convert `fruit` to an array and then loop over each item in that array to see the value of the `switch` change.

```js
var fruits = ["orange", "apple", "pear"];

for(var fruit of fruits) {
  switch (fruit) {
      case "orange":
          console.log('orange is a fruit')
          break;
      case "hotdog":
          console.log('hot dog is meat')
          break;
      case "pear":
          console.log('pear is a fruit')
      default:
          //document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = 'NONE';
  }
}
```

(Changed to `console.log()` to avoid the alert popups in the snippet)

Comment: This works but I am getting a 'ReferenceError:' at the end that fruit is not defined.?

Comment: hmm the snippet as presented above doesn't seem to have that `ReferenceError` so it might be additional code you have written around it?

Comment: Bingo yes, thank you for the answer! It was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The declare with `fruit = ("orange", "apple", "pear");`

the fruit variable will have value `"pear"`

You should change it to array as

```js
fruit = ["orange", "apple", "pear"];

for(var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++){
switch (fruit[i]) {
    case "orange":
        alert('orange is a fruit')
        break;
    case "hotdog":
        alert('hot dog is meat')
        break;
    case "pear":
        alert('pear is a fruit')
    default:
        document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = 'NONE';
}
}
```

```html
<div id="heading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare fruit variable with var/let/const keyword then wrap elements of array between square brackets . Access array elements by his index (fruit[0] equals 'orange')

```js
var fruit = ["orange", "apple", "pear"];
//fruit[0] == orange
//fruit[1] == apple
//fruit[2] == pear

switch (fruit[0]) {
    case "orange":
        alert('orange is a fruit');
        break;
    case "hotdog":
        alert('hot dog is meat');
        break;
    case "pear":
        alert('pear is a fruit');
    default:
        document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = 'NONE';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be a better way to organize your data:

```
var data = {
  "orange": "fruit", 
  "apple": "fruit", 
  "pear": "fruit", 
  "hot dog": "meat"
};

console.log(data["orange"]); // fruit
console.log(data["hot dog"]); // meat
```